# winhttp and visual studio code - complete newb and issue with 'undefined references' when building

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, winhttp

I have about 20 years of php, js, css, html, xml, etc (all the web stuff), but nothing in C++ - complete newbie here.  I pick up code quick, but do best with working examples that I can 'play' with to understand better.

I have VS Code installed, the c/c++ extension installed, and the MinGW-x64 compiler (I was following along with https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp.  I also installed the latest Windows SDK.

I'm trying to use the example below, I believe I found here on SO, that does a simple test 'POST' to a php script.  I'm sure this is laughable to most and things wrong, but again this is all foreign to me right now other than a basic understanding of what is going on purely from knowing other languages.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinHttp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream> //getchar
#include <fstream>

#pragma comment(lib, "winhttp.lib")

using namespace std;

std::wstring get_utf16(const std::string &str, int codepage)
{
    if (str.empty()) return std::wstring();
    int sz = MultiByteToWideChar(codepage, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), 0, 0);
    std::wstring res(sz, 0);
    MultiByteToWideChar(codepage, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), &res[0], sz);
    return res;
}

string HttpsWebRequestPost(string domain, string url, string dat)
{
    //Extra
    LPSTR  data = const_cast<char *>(dat.c_str());;
    DWORD data_len = strlen(data);

    wstring sdomain = get_utf16(domain, CP_UTF8);
    wstring surl = get_utf16(url, CP_UTF8);
    string response;

    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    DWORD dwDownloaded = 0;
    LPSTR pszOutBuffer;
    BOOL  bResults = FALSE;
    HINTERNET  hSession = NULL,
        hConnect = NULL,
        hRequest = NULL;
    LPCWSTR additionalHeaders = L"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    DWORD headersLength = -1;

    // Use WinHttpOpen to obtain a session handle.
    hSession = WinHttpOpen(L"WinHTTP Example/1.0",
        WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);

    // Specify an HTTP server.
    if (hSession)
        hConnect = WinHttpConnect(hSession, sdomain.c_str(),
            INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, 0);

    // Create an HTTP request handle.
    if (hConnect)
        hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, L"POST", surl.c_str(),
            NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER,
            WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES,
            0);

    // Send a request.
    if (hRequest)

        bResults = WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest,
                                        additionalHeaders,
                                        headersLength,
                                        (LPVOID)data,
                                        data_len,
                                        data_len, 
                                        0);

    // End the request.
    if (bResults)
        bResults = WinHttpReceiveResponse(hRequest, NULL);

    // Keep checking for data until there is nothing left.
    if (bResults)
    {
        do
        {
            // Check for available data.
            dwSize = 0;
            if (!WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(hRequest, &dwSize))
                printf("Error %u in WinHttpQueryDataAvailable.\n",
                    GetLastError());

            // Allocate space for the buffer.
            pszOutBuffer = new char[dwSize + 1];
            if (!pszOutBuffer)
            {
                printf("Out of memory\n");
                dwSize = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                // Read the data.
                ZeroMemory(pszOutBuffer, dwSize + 1);

                if (!WinHttpReadData(hRequest, (LPVOID)pszOutBuffer,
                    dwSize, &dwDownloaded))
                    printf("Error %u in WinHttpReadData.\n", GetLastError());
                else
                    //printf("%s", pszOutBuffer);
                    response = response + string(pszOutBuffer);
                // Free the memory allocated to the buffer.
                delete[] pszOutBuffer;
            }
        } while (dwSize > 0);
    }

    // Report any errors.
    if (!bResults)
        printf("Error %d has occurred.\n", GetLastError());

    // Close any open handles.
    if (hRequest) WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
    if (hConnect) WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
    if (hSession) WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);

    return response;
}

int main()
{ 
    printf("RESPONSE: %S\n", HttpsWebRequestPost("example.com", "/example.php", "value=1000").c_str());
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Upon building I am getting the following in the console :

```
Starting build...
Build finished with errors(s):
C:\Users\*****\AppData\Local\Temp\cczChaiv.o: In function `HttpsWebRequestPost(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
C:/*****/test.cpp:42: undefined reference to `WinHttpOpen'
C:/*****/test.cpp:49: undefined reference to `WinHttpConnect'
C:/*****/test.cpp:54: undefined reference to `WinHttpOpenRequest'
C:/*****/test.cpp:62: undefined reference to `WinHttpSendRequest'
C:/*****/test.cpp:72: undefined reference to `WinHttpReceiveResponse'
C:/*****/test.cpp:81: undefined reference to `WinHttpQueryDataAvailable'
C:/*****/test.cpp:97: undefined reference to `WinHttpReadData'
C:/*****/test.cpp:114: undefined reference to `WinHttpCloseHandle'
C:/*****/test.cpp:115: undefined reference to `WinHttpCloseHandle'
C:/*****/test.cpp:116: undefined reference to `WinHttpCloseHandle'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The terminal process terminated with exit code: -1.
```

Comment: `#pragma comment(lib, "winhttp.lib")`: This is a native extension I know from MSVC (but try never to use - it's non-standard). Are you sure that MinGW g++ supports this? (`#pragma`s are compiler specific always. There are only few which are supported by most compilers.) Try to give the `Winhttp.lib` as command line argument for linking.

Comment: FYI: [gcc -L / -l option flags](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-l.html)

Comment: @Scheff I have no idea - never touched any of this before.  How would I add it a command line argument for linking?  Would I be better off just installing VS community as it has its own compiler as far as I understood when looking online.

Comment: I use Visual Studio in daily business and can warmly recommend it. However, the link options of gcc are how it's done in most C/C++ compilers. It wouldn't hurt to become familiar with this. The `#pragma comment(lib` thing is really Microsoft specific... (though even Microsoft supports the usual way of command line arguments for linking). ;-)

Comment: So I copied winhttp.lib from the sdk folder to a folder called 'libs' in my project folder.  `gcc test.cpp -L /libs/ -l winhttp -o outfile.exe`, but now get a ton of 'undefined reference' errors such as `undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::empty() const'` when doing so.  Sorry, this is all new to me.

Comment: Figured this out - g++ not gcc should be used.